# Automate write.csv

Tags: r

I have  a large data.table (df.iso) that I want to split up and write to separate files. Is is possible to automate the write.csv function?

```
> colnames(df.iso)
 [1] "V1"                          "Seq"                         "../trimmed/60G.tally.fasta" 
 [4] "../trimmed/73R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/246R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/402G.tally.fasta"
 [7] "../trimmed/93G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/100R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/124G.tally.fasta"
[10] "../trimmed/350R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/126G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/379R.tally.fasta"
[13] "../trimmed/134R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/57R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/243G.tally.fasta"
[16] "../trimmed/361R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/388R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/94R.tally.fasta" 
[19] "../trimmed/270R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/240G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/46R.tally.fasta" 
[22] "../trimmed/356R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/77G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/122R.tally.fasta"
[25] "../trimmed/35R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/246G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/367G.tally.fasta"
[28] "../trimmed/93R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/305R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/82R.tally.fasta" 
[31] "../trimmed/48R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/377R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/106R.tally.fasta"
[34] "../trimmed/57G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/279G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/400R.tally.fasta"
[37] "../trimmed/60R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/335R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/192G.tally.fasta"
[40] "../trimmed/239R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/167G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/70R.tally.fasta" 
[43] "../trimmed/68R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/367R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/235R.tally.fasta"
[46] "../trimmed/141R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/342R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/55R.tally.fasta" 
[49] "../trimmed/356G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/35G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/267G.tally.fasta"
[52] "../trimmed/402R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/55G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/267R.tally.fasta"
[55] "../trimmed/235G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/301G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/70G.tally.fasta" 
[58] "../trimmed/106G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/240R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/126R.tally.fasta"
[61] "../trimmed/73G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/82G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/77R.tally.fasta" 
[64] "../trimmed/185R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/167R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/124R.tally.fasta"
[67] "../trimmed/270G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/94G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/400G.tally.fasta"
[70] "../trimmed/26R.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/377G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/361G.tally.fasta"
[73] "../trimmed/192R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/141G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/301R.tally.fasta"
[76] "../trimmed/366R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/261G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/46G.tally.fasta" 
[79] "../trimmed/122G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/243R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/299R.tally.fasta"
[82] "../trimmed/279R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/350G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/388G.tally.fasta"
[85] "../trimmed/335G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/366G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/48G.tally.fasta" 
[88] "../trimmed/26G.tally.fasta"  "../trimmed/185G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/342G.tally.fasta"
[91] "../trimmed/305G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/261R.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/100G.tally.fasta"
[94] "../trimmed/379G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/134G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/68G.tally.fasta" 
[97] "../trimmed/299G.tally.fasta" "../trimmed/239G.tally.fasta"
```

I use this function to define and write the subfiles:

```
 write.table(df.iso[,c("Seq","../trimmed/60G.tally.fasta"), with=FALSE], 
 file="IsomiR_60G.txt",
 sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to write tab-delimited files per your existing code. For that, you could do:

```
for (col in colnames(df.iso)[-(1:2)]) {
  filename <- sub("^\\.*/trimmed/([0-9A-Z]+)\\..*$", "IsomiR_\\1.txt", col)
  write.table(df.iso[, c("Seq", col), with = FALSE], 
  file = filename,
  sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

This uses a `for` loop to work through every column except the first 2.

Comment: It seems to have a bug, the output is only column names: x
Seq
../trimmed/26G.tally.fasta

Comment: @BioMan could you clarify? Did any files get written?

Comment: The files got written, but they only had the column names in it. No other data. Remember that I want all rows to be written, not only the column names. The data.frame has 300 000  rows

Comment: I think this must be a data.table. Can you do `class(df.iso)`?

Comment: Yes, I read it using fread. > class(df.iso)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: @BioMan hence why you had with=FALSE. Should work with that back in - see edit.